# How to get substring between two same characters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string value as `abc:language-letters-alphs/EnglishData:7844val:` . I want to extract the part `language-letters-alphs/EnglishData`, the value between first `:` and second `:`. Is there a way to do it without storing each substrings on different vars? I want to do it the ES6 way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this **two ways** easily. You can choose what suits you best.

Using [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Use split method to get your desired text.

> The `split()` method divides a String into an ordered list of substrings, puts these substrings into an array, and returns the array. The division is done by searching for a pattern; where the pattern is provided as the first parameter in the method's call.

```js
let str = 'abc:language-letters-alphs/EnglishData:7844val:'.split(':')

console.log(str[1]) //language-letters-alphs/EnglishData
```

Using [String#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

You can use [ Method but in that you have define the exact `indexes` of the words you want to extract.

> The `slice()` method extracts a section of a string and returns it as a new string, *without modifying the original string*.

```js
let str = 'abc:language-letters-alphs/EnglishData:7844val:'

console.log(str.slice(4, 38)) //language-letters-alphs/EnglishData
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const str = "abc:language-letters-alphs/EnglishData:7844val:"
const relevantPart = str.split(':')[1]
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
console.log("abc:language-letters-alphs/EnglishData:7844val:".split(":")[1])
```